# Keyboard Panel to choose diiferent views(Custom)

Tags: android-studio, android-custom-view, navigationbar, custom-keyboard

I need to make a Panel on which I'll be able to switch between different custom keyboard views that i have designed.

Something like this
[My keypad with navigation panel and custom view of my Numeric keypad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzBWw.png)

Answer (score 1):

At least two strategies can be applied.

1. Put your custom KeyboardView inside another ViewGroup, ex.:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            \>

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Wazup?!"
       />

   <org.dodroid.customime.CustomKeyboardView
       android:id="@+id/keyboard"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:keyBackground="@drawable/samplekeybackground"
       android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
       android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard"
       />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Instead of TextView can be your custom panel.

2. Create one more Row at top with navigation buttons.